# How can I derive types from function argument?

Tags: typescript

I want a function `createApi` that will infer types based on the config passed in.

Here is what I have so far:

```
export type EndpointConfig<Input, Resp> = (http: Http) => RequestConfig<Input, Resp>;

export type RequestConfig<Input, Resp> = {
  query: (input: Input) => Promise<Resp>
}

export type ApiConfig<M extends EndpointMap> = {
  endpoints: { [K in keyof M]: EndpointConfig<M[K]['input'], M[K]['resp']> }
}

type EndpointMap = { [key: string]: { resp: any, input: any } };

export const createApi = <M extends EndpointMap>(config: ApiConfig<M>): ApiConfig<M> => {
  // omit implementation
  return config;
};

export interface Http {
  get: <T>(url: string) => Promise<T>
}

// ============ using createApi ============

interface User {
  username: string
}

export const api = createApi({
  endpoints: {
    users: http => ({
      // here is where the types should come from
      query: (input: string) => http.get<User>(`/users/${input}`),
    }),
  },
});

const { users } = api.endpoints;
// typeof users is EndpointConfig<any, any>
// but I want EndpointConfig<string, User>
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N5kxMW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a value of type

```
type ApiConfig<M extends EndpointMap> = {
  endpoints: { [K in keyof M]: EndpointConfig<M[K]['input'], M[K]['resp']> }
}
```

for some `M`, the compiler really can't properly infer `M` from it.  To do so would require that types could be synthesized from arbitrary [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) types like `T['input']` or `T['resp']`, but TypeScript doesn't currently do that.  There's an open feature request for it at [microsoft/TypeScript#51612](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51612), but for now it's not part of the language.

---

Until an unless that gets implemented you'll need to work around it.  It's a lot easier to infer a type parameter to be exactly the type of the passed in function argument, and then evaluate your desired type *from* that.  So instead of `config: ApiConfig<M>`, you'd have `config: {endpoints: E}` and then return either `E` or some type that is computed from `E`.  For example:

```
export const createApi = <
  E extends Record<keyof E, EndpointConfig<any, any>>
>(config: { endpoints: E }): {
  endpoints: { [K in keyof E]:
    E[K] extends EndpointConfig<infer I, infer R> ?
    EndpointConfig<I, R> : E[K]
  }
} => {
  // omit implementation
  return config;
};
```

And now when we test it:

```
export const api = createApi({
  endpoints: {
    users: http => ({
      query: (input: string) => http.get<User>(`/users/${input}`),
    }),
  },
});

/* const api: {
    endpoints: {
        users: EndpointConfig<string, User>;
    };
} */

const { users } = api.endpoints;
// const users: EndpointConfig<string, User>
```

You get the behavior you're looking for.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiA7AJpAlhmAYQgwDNcBzAHgEkMwBXGAGjgCVgBnMAPjgF44ACgAWMGGABccABLiwASgF8OARwZciJctTqMW7LrwDcAKFOhIsBMlRqNnLWUq16TVh259BAb1Nw4dWAoRGkhfH1pPSYlfj4ABSgIAFtcTmAqT15TAF9zS2h4AGMSRzgiqGAAQxhgAEEwXAE4Kn90OFBa7E5DEqgsKgBrYEQIUnRWTBwIfCcdKiqMRFZFxB4eUx4hEucKaR8O7DwCTmk0OByFfbbgI5mT-bgAbQBpOHw4YdHxtABdSTaATQr1+HRAXSwPSmxzmLnwpGCcBorHhiLYfAA-ID0HdZsRdrQPHwziC2nkcso4H4AgB6GlwFK4eC4ZJgAA2wGStxgNVwJDalRgDCgGHK2koZhyZgs4EK7wIwVIVSKqDkEipbQowBg0ioABUtsK2dJHFB8BRYgkkql0vqNnlTHSBPwXa63YIGJxzeVKjV6o1ne73eZZorlagAKrpKAagKe4IYKpck0wM0YCi5fKy6w7MpVAOCCrVWoNXBCamHaazU6xgJweNQGtidVxYQVuuBDQhMIRJgptMWynNsAAOi1MCoUeCWwABjSG5waQASHy9mA5GcKZjYy7bgI5beXaU0gBUYoweca1w7tyrD1rHbj0Zr0PusOopvNrCnUB4Zg7Uq5HAJ40uYubwAcC4XM0+a4COt4wpwZhOuB9bPmcuIEPi8yfum37RjwQA)